# Project Euler Problem 1: Multiples of 3 or 5

Tags: beginner, programming-challenge, rust

The following is my solution to [Project Euler Problem 1: Multiples of 3 or 5](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1).

```
use clap::Parser;
use std::ops::RangeFrom;
use std::process::exit;

const VALID_NUMBER_RANGE: RangeFrom<u64> = 2..;

#[derive(Parser)]
struct Arguments {
    #[arg(index = 1)]
    first_number: u64,
    #[arg(index = 2)]
    second_number: u64,
    #[arg(index = 3)]
    threshold: u64,
}

fn main() {
    let arguments = Arguments::parse();
    let first_number = arguments.first_number;
    let second_number = arguments.second_number;
    let threshold = arguments.threshold;

    if !VALID_NUMBER_RANGE.contains(&first_number) {
        eprintln!("Error: First number out of range: {}", first_number);
        exit(1);
    } else if !VALID_NUMBER_RANGE.contains(&second_number) {
        eprintln!("Error: Second number out of range: {}", second_number);
        exit(1);
    }

    let pair_multiples_sum = sum_pair_multiples(first_number, second_number, threshold);
    println!("{}", pair_multiples_sum);
}

fn sum_multiples(number: u64, threshold: u64) -> u64 {
    (number..threshold).filter(|n| n % number == 0).sum()
}

fn find_greatest_common_divisor(first_number: u64, second_number: u64) -> u64 {
    if second_number == 0 {
        first_number
    } else {
        find_greatest_common_divisor(second_number, first_number % second_number)
    }
}

fn find_least_common_multiple(first_number: u64, second_number: u64) -> u64 {
    let greatest_common_divisor = find_greatest_common_divisor(first_number, second_number);

    first_number * second_number / greatest_common_divisor
}

fn sum_pair_multiples(first_number: u64, second_number: u64, threshold: u64) -> u64 {
    let least_common_multiple = find_least_common_multiple(first_number, second_number);

    let mut first_number_multiples_sum: u64 = 0;
    let mut second_number_multiples_sum: u64 = 0;
    let mut least_common_multiple_multiples_sum: u64 = 0;

    rayon::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(|_| first_number_multiples_sum = sum_multiples(first_number, threshold));
        s.spawn(|_| second_number_multiples_sum = sum_multiples(second_number, threshold));
        s.spawn(|_| {
            least_common_multiple_multiples_sum = sum_multiples(least_common_multiple, threshold)
        });
    });

    first_number_multiples_sum + second_number_multiples_sum - least_common_multiple_multiples_sum
}
```

How can I improve my code? Any form of improvement is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation is far more complex than the problem calls for. Maybe that's practice for more complex problems?

You don't need to handle arguments, the problem has fixed parameters.

You don't need threading, this problem is far too small to warrant that. By the way `sum_multiples` can be expressed in closed form, in that case you *definitely* don't need threading, even if `threshold` was large (which it isn't so it doesn't actually matter, but it's an opportunity to explore some mathematics and that's what Project Euler is about).

> ```
> fn find_greatest_common_divisor
> ```

Generally mathematical functions (especially the more "basic" or "light weight" ones, such as GCD) are exempted from the guideline to make function names verbs. Prefixing them with "find" or "compute" is not useful, just noisy.

Comment: The way Project Euler is written, you could usually just print the answer and technically have the fastest possible solution. The way I usually interpret the spirit of the challenge is to write a general algorithm that can pre-calculate a result as a compile-time constnat, as a `const fn` if possible.

Comment: So it makes sense that OP is picking a more-general problem to solve, of which the required testcase is one special case. It is, as you say, much more complex and inefficient than it needs to be.

Comment: @Davislor there is a significant difference IMO between working out a general algorithm, and writing a bunch of code that doesn't meaningfully contribute to solving the problem (gold plating, basically).